# Highest resolution with ps2pdf following the dvi > dvi2ps > ps2pdf route

Tags: ps2pdf, resolution

I would like to know the highest resolution that I can set in the conversion of a postscript file to its pdf file using `ps2pdf`. In **Ghostscript** help pages I see:

**The default internal resolution for pdfwrite is 720dpi**

This is achieved by a  `-r720` with `ps2pdf`.

Normally in my `dvi2ps` conversion I have a high resolution setting: `-D7200`. So can we use the same resolution with `ps2pdf`? Of course the final printout depends on the resolution that the printer allows.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

### dvips:

```
dvips -D10000 -t unknown input.dvi
```

### ghostscript:

```
gswin64c -r10000 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o output.pdf input.ps
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a source of information for these numbers of 10000? 1 vote up.